# How can I get the previous index?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a click, task to get the current and previous index of an item.

```js
$('.item').click(function() {
  var index = $('.item').index(this),
    indexLast = 'here prev index';

  $('.result').text(index + ', ' + indexLast);
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  background-color: #2ecc71;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #3498db;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div class="result"></div>
```

Example: we clicked on 3. And then on 6. I need to get. index == 6, lastIndex == 3.

Comment: Collect the clicked indices into an array, or if the last index is specifically needed only, store it into variable outside of the event listener function.

Comment: Can you plase write code on my example? I'm just getting started. The option with the function is more preferable.

Comment: What do you want the last index be on the very first click? -1? The empty string? Something else?

Comment: On first click lastIndex can be null. I need that at the subsequent there was last index.

Comment: Declare `indexlast` outside of the event handler and assign `null` to it. Then as the last line in the event handler, do `indexLast = index;`. That way `indexLast` always contains the index of the previously clicked element, and `null` on the very first click.

Comment: @Teemu-callmewhateveryouwant thank you. khoekman write example and it dawned on me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean like this:

```js
    var indexLast = '';
    $('.item').click(function() {
      var index = $('.item').index($(this));

      $('.result').text( 'current: ' + index + ', previous: ' + indexLast);
      indexLast = index
    });
```

```css
    .wrap {
      display: flex;`enter code here`
    }

    .item {
      background-color: #2ecc71;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      margin: 0 10px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .item:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: #3498db;
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: The indexLast is outside of the click function to keep track of the previous click.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this. Hope it will work for you.

```
var totalClickedArray = [];
$('.item').click(function() {
  var index = $('.item').index(this);
  totalClickedArray.push(index);
  var arraySize = totalClickedArray.length;
  console.log('last index:' + totalClickedArray[arraySize - 2],  ' new index:' + index);
});
```

Comment: I understand your idea. Put a click in array and then return - 1 for last index. Unfortunately it does not work. last index = current index.

Comment: You just need `arraySize - 2` as arraySize is 0 based

Comment: totalClickedArray[arraySize - 2] will work for you. Please accept the answer. A downvote haras who puts time effort to answer you.

Comment: Didn't need a downvote for a simple -1 vs -2 - works fine and records click history not just last

Answer (score 0):

```js
'use strict';
let indexLast = 'here prev index', current_i = 'here prev index'

$('.item').click(function() {
  let index = $('.item').index(this),
  last_i = current_i;
  current_i = index;
  $('.result').text(current_i + ', ' + last_i);
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  background-color: #2ecc71;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #3498db;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div class="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to storing in a variable, you can add a class to the one you click and then check for that class next time you click.

```
$(".wrap>.item").click(function() {
    var last = $(this).siblings(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");

   // output last.text() / $(this).text() as needed
});
```

Using OPs buttons and this.last index() as specified in the question:

```js
$('.item').click(function() {
  var indexLast = $(".item.clicked").index();
  var index = $(this).index();
  $(this).addClass("clicked").siblings().removeClass("clicked");
  $('.result').text(index + ', ' + indexLast);
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  background-color: #2ecc71;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #3498db;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div class="result"></div>
```

Extending this to show the active/lastactive using css gives:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".wrap>.item").click(function() {
    var last = $(this)
      .siblings()
      .removeClass("lastactive")
      .filter(".active")
      .removeClass("active")
      .addClass("lastactive");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 20px;
}

.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.lastactive {
  background-color: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: I do not think that it is necessary to use DOM in my case.

Comment: Maybe not in your case, but this also keeps it self-contained in the case you wanted multiple of these on the same page.  Adding a global variable is generally frowned upon and would need multiple variables / duplicate code each time.

Comment: In any case, thank you for your experience. I don't have a global variable. I'm using a module for this piece of code.

Comment: No worries - maybe it will help someone else in future.  Modularising this is also a great solution to having multiple instances on the page (not clear from other answers).